# web.config to redirect except some given IPs

Tags: redirects, iis

I'm looking for a web.config which is equivalent as the .htaccess file below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^321\.321\.321\.321
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/coming-soon\.html$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /coming-soon.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Which redirects everyone to a coming soon page except for the given IPs. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with IIS.

Comment: I think you want to use {REMOTE_ADDR} instead of {REMOTE_HOST}

Comment: Take a look at this brief tutorial: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using IIS7, what you will want to do is use the [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module.  With that installed on your server, you can actually import .htaccess mod_rewrite rules directly and it will convert them to the correct syntax and add it to the web.config of your site.  Information about that can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules).

In its raw form, your mod_rewrite rules will be converted to this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REMOTE_HOST}" pattern="^123\.123\.123\.123" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REMOTE_HOST}" pattern="^321\.321\.321\.321" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/coming-soon\.html$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="/coming-soon.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

You will most likely need to test and tune the rule to meet your needs.  I believe it was mentioned in a comment about using {REMOTE_ADDR} instead of {REMOTE_HOST}.  I do agree with that if you are looking for a specific IP address.